# How to create a file with filename argv[1].blabla? in c

Tags: c, file

I know how to create a file, but i can't create a file with the extension .blabla. Isn't it possible?

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking? I have no idea.

Comment: It would be wise to post your code and better explain your goal.  As it stands, this cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fixed length and `snprintf` as Tim Cooper says, or you can use `malloc` and string functions included in `string.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #define EXT ".blabla"
    char *s;
    FILE *f;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    s = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + strlen(EXT) + 1);
    if (s == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    strcpy(s, argv[1]);
    strcat(s, EXT);
    f = fopen(s, "w");
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fclose(f);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not possible... Extension is added so that a program can detect his own file. If you need further to use .blabla files then you can create. You can use name the file directly as `filename.blabla`.